# Touchable opacity in react native onpress working at some points but not working at centre an all with absolute

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Touchable opacity onPress working when we click at edges, when we click on center its not working

I have tried

- importing from react-native-gestures
- giving z-index
- wrapping with view

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
<View style={{bottom:0,width:'100%',height:44,flex:1,position:"absolute"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=>handleLogin()} 
                style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    flex:1,
                    height: 44,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    width:"100%",
                    }}
                >  
                    <LinearGradient 
                        start={{x: 0.5, y: 0}} 
                        end={{x: 0.861, y: 1}}  
                        locations={[0,0.867,1]} 
                        style={{
                            width:"100%",
                            height:"100%",
                            justifyContent:"center",
                            flexDirection:"row",
                            alignItems:"center",
                            // zIndex:99
                        }}
                        colors={['#DD9D18', '#FFEF6C', '#EEC733' ]}>
                        <Text style={GenericStyles.h5StyleTwo} >Sign In</Text>
                        <SignInIcon fill="#000" style={{marginLeft:8}}/>
                    </LinearGradient>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `LinearGradient` or `SignInIcon` component having some gesture detector, please checkout that.